# Google Sheets Order By Query isnt showing any data

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to bring in my list of employees from another file and have them sorted when they come in. When I do this:

```
=QUERY(importrange(K1, "Employees"), "Select *", 1)
```

Everything works great, but as soon as I add the order by method,

```
=QUERY(importrange(K1, "Employees"), "Select * order by Col4", 1)
```

It no longer works and just shows the header. Col4 is the correct column and if I use "Select Col4" all of the correct data shows up once again. Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: include the examole sheet or images of different states.

Comment: check the bottom of the sheet.  any chance your data is way down at the bottom?

Comment: Could you share the sample sheet to check how the data is arranged?

Comment: @MattKing You figured it out. As soon as I added a where clause for not null everything worked as intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your `IMPORTRANGE()` function in curly brackets. I was able to reproduce (what I believe to be) a similar error in my sheet.

When I defined a range to query, it would not work when using "Col4". This did work when I used `D`, though.
[image]

However, when I then placed the range into curly brackets, it understood `Col4`, and was able to order it.
[image]

---

Given that you did not get an error and instead got no values, make sure that the values in the column you are sorting by are of one majority datatype.

For example:
[image: ex]

In this, the majority of column 4 are numbers, so when the data is sorted all the letters are left out.

My best advice is to simply check your datatypes. Dissimilar types won't sort properly with `QUERY`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the formatting of the source data is not mixed.

Example: Text, Number, ...
Format the columns in the same format to the last row.